# Show value of select dropdown in meta box

Tags: metabox, post-meta

I have created a meta box which has a select dropdown list and i want to show it in the post as a user selects a particular option from meta box.I cant figure it out how its done.Here is my meta box code.

```
<?php
function display_post_options(){
    global $post;
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'post_options_nonce' ); 
    $post_options_select_value =  get_post_meta($post->ID,'post_options_select',true);

?>



    <label for="options-select">Choose Your Post Layout:</label>
    <select name='post_options_select' id="options-select">
        <option id='right-sidebar' value='right' name='right_sidebar' <?php selected($post_options_select_value, 'right'); ?> >Right sidebar</option>
        <option id='left-sidebar' value="left" name='left_sidebar' <?php selected($post_options_select_value, 'left'); ?>>Left Sidebar</option>
        <option id='no-sidebar' value="no" name='no_sidebar' <?php selected($post_options_select_value, 'no'); ?>>No Sidebar</option>
    </select>


<?php
}

function post_options(){
    add_meta_box( 
        'post-options',
        'Post Options',
        'display_post_options',
        'post',
        'advanced',
        'high',
        $callback_args
    );
}

function save_post_options($post_id){

    if (if_user_can_save($post_id, 'post_options_nonce')) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'post_options_select', $_POST['post_options_select']);
    }

}

function if_user_can_save($post_id, $nonce){

    //Check if post is autosave
    $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave($post_id);
    //Check if it is a Revision
    $is_revision = wp_is_post_revision($post_id);
    //Is the nonce valid
    $is_valid_nonce = ( isset( $_POST[ $nonce ] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[ $nonce ], basename( __FILE__ ) ) );
    return !($is_autosave || $is_revision) && $is_valid_nonce;

}

function display_content( $content ){
    $test = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'options-select', true);
    $content .= $test;
    print_r($test);
    return $content;
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'post_options');
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_post_options', 10, 2 );
add_action('the_content', 'display_content');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your meta option is `post_options_select`. You are using wrong meta key `options-select` in function `display_content`.

But main point is that, you cannot control the sidebar layout from `the_content` filter. If selected option is 'No Sidebar' then you need to hide sidebar in your template. `the_content` only contains the content of the post. How it should be displayed whether with sidebar or not, it should be controlled while including sidebar.

Comment: i know i cant do that with the content but if i have the values i can change the css dynamically with redux framework.if your have better alternative for that please let me  know.